# Bootstrap Shadow Dropdown Menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, shadow

What I'd like to do is, to have a shadow like in picture 1 at the same
place in picture 2. The arrows show the place where the shadow should show.
However I could not find any code snippet to place a shadow right under the navbar
, when the dropdown menu is shown. Maybe you can help me.

First picture: http://abload.de/image.php?img=arrowbkkd5.png
Second picture: http://abload.de/image.php?img=arrow2lsjum.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a div under your navbar and give it a margin-top -x px like this:

```
    .gradient{
         background: #6393c1; /* Old browsers */
         background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #6393c1 1%, #cfe7fa 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
         background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#6393c1), color-stop(100%,#cfe7fa)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
         background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #6393c1 1%,#cfe7fa 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
         background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #6393c1 1%,#cfe7fa 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
         background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #6393c1 1%,#cfe7fa 100%); /* IE10+ */
         background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #6393c1 1%,#cfe7fa 100%); /* W3C */
         filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6393c1', endColorstr='#cfe7fa',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
         height:20px;
         margin-top:-20px;
     }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JvZwL/)
, you can make the gradient with a tool named [CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). Then define your height and align it with your navbar. Hope this helps you enough, if not, ask freely.

### EDIT, dismiss previous code

I've reworked a bootply for you. You can find it [here](http://www.bootply.com/Vf81oNvs1q). Basically what I did was add the gradient below the navbar. Give it a margin-top equaling the height of the navbar. Then override the bootstrap class dropdown-menu like beneath, the margin-top equals the height of your gradient. I hope this is what you need.

```
.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu{
    margin-top:20px !important;
}
```

### EDIT 2:

Okay, I think I've got it now.Take a look [here](http://www.bootply.com/iCMhacxV3U). If you don't need the gradient on desktop devices, you can hide it with display none and then add in your media query, display block. But that's up to you.

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-collapse{
        position:absolute;
        background:#222;
        width:100%;
        top:70px;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a gradient as you said and it works in the same way like your example. However that was not excatly what I wanted. What i want is a Shadow BETWEEN the navbar and the dropdown menu (the one that appears when the navbar collapses). But if I use your code example, the shadow disappears behind the dropdownmenu and i can't see it anymore. Here is another example of what i mean: http://abload.de/image.php?img=newgvek3.png

Comment: I am sorry but you misunderstood again. You made a example with the wrong dropdownmenu. I made two screenshots of your example: http://abload.de/image.php?img=einskjjqs.png  This button appears if you make the windows smaller, if you click on it a dropdownmenu appears http://abload.de/image.php?img=zweilnj6p.png BUT IN THIS DROPDOWNMENU is no shadow below our former "navigation bar". I hope this helps to understand.

Comment: Can you upvote the answer and mark it as the solution?

Comment: unfortunately i can not upvote it, because i do not have enough reputation :-(

Comment: You can eventually :)